# How I can handling same entity with multiple databases in NestJs TypeOrm?

Tags: oracle, nestjs, typeorm

**app.module.ts**

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  ...defaultOptions,
  name: 'test1',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
}),
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  ...defaultOptions,
  name: 'test2',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
}),
TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Verification], 'test1'),
TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Verification], 'test2'),
```

**users.module.ts**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Verification], 'test1'),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Verification], 'test2')
    ],
    providers: [UsersResolver, UsersService],
    exports: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

**users.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User, 'test1') private readonly test1Users: Repository<User>,
    @InjectRepository(Verification, 'werpsys')
    private readonly test1Verifications: Repository<Verification>,

    @InjectRepository(User, 'werpsys') private readonly test2Users: Repository<User>,
    @InjectRepository(Verification, 'werpsys')
    private readonly test2Verifications: Repository<Verification>,
    
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) { }
```

1. Has the same entity
2. Multiple DBs with different addresses (30 pieces)

It is currently being implemented with Nest Js, and I would like to ask you if the only way to solve multiple databases is to handle them like the above code by applying all the injection.

If the user hands over the parameter "test1", I would like to get the value from the DB accordingly, but I am asking if there is a good way.

My current thoughts are as follows, but is there any way?

```
if (parm === "test1) {
 ...do Something with test1Users
}else if (parm === "test2") {
 ...do Something with test2Users
}else if (parm === "test3") {
 ...do Something with test3Users
}
...
```

I think it is not good, but I don't have a idea good way to solve it.
Please help me.

Comment: Hello, Did you find any solution on this ?